# How can I find case studies of harsh reactions of conservative forces in response to sweeping reforms?

Tags: democracy, reference-request, political-leaders, coup

I am working on New Institutional economists' theories (in particular those of North, Khan and Weingast) and I am looking for case studies of reformers miscalculating their powers and being the subject of a significant backlash from conservative forces.

Leaders like Allende, Zelaya or Arbenz can serve as examples of reformers who face coups which reverse long lasting popular efforts. How can I find similiar cases?

Comment: I think you really should try to use less subjective terms & examples in your question.  E.g. a good many people are likely to think that a Marxist takeover really doesn't meet the definition of "reform".

Comment: Making changes might be a better alternative for the term. Redistributive arrangements and land reforms are the focus of my attention as I am working on the case of US backed coup against Musaddeq.

Comment: @jamesqf What's subjective about the word “reform”? I get a lot of people have strong feelings regarding a figure like Allende (probably less regarding Arbenz or Zelaya) but that seems like the most neutral way to put it.

Comment: @Relaxed: Because how one views "[r]edistributive arrangements and land reforms" entirely depends on one's subjective point of view.  If you expect to profit by those changes (either directly, or because you hope to rise in the new government, you might see them as reforms.  If you happen to be prosperous and/or a landowner, you could well see them as theft, potentially followed by your murder.  See for instance such "reforms" as the French Revolution, Russian Revolution, Nazi takeover of Germany, China's "Cultural Revolution", and many more.

Comment: @jamesqf I know that's where you want to go but that's the point of the word “reform”. It's still an accurate description.

Comment: [This article](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1080/03066150.2017.1380628) came to my mind... But the 5 cases in that article are basically reactions against movements for land reform "from below", and the question seems to be focused on leaders who imposed land reform "from above".

Comment: How to find case studies appropriate for your research is a great question, but probably not on topic here (commentors have often reminded me this isn't political science.se). I'm recommending this be moved to academia.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a theory but need case material. How do you find it?

### Networking

Your question doesn't specify what kind of expertise you have or what field in particular you may be working in. It sounds like you have a theoretical focus, but lack specific regional or contextual expertise. If that's the case, then your best bet is to ask your colleagues for case studies that may be of interest.

In comparative politics it's not uncommon to group people into whether they study  cross-national theoretical subjects (populism, authoritarian regimes, electoral behavior, courts, etc.) or whether they focus in a specific region (European politics, Caribbean politics, etc.).  Often people need from each group need to work together.

This sounds like what you are describing. If so, try asking around departments dedicated to regional studies, or colleagues that have that kind of expertise. If you can clearly convey what you need for an interesting case study, they may know of examples that you can use.

### Secondary Research

Odds are you have been reading literature related to the  theories and ideas you are interested in. What examples do those authors discuss? And why not use the same case studies they do?

There are some benefits to this approach. By selecting the same cases that are already used in existing literature you maximize how well your findings can be contrasted or integrated with existing research. As an example, Robert Putnam (Making Democracy Work) famously studies political culture in Italy. He studied how different political values related to cooperation in northern and southern Italy led to totally different policy environments.

Who cares what happens in Italy, you might say? Well, a generation before Putnam another scientist named Edward Banfield had also famously studied political culture in Italy. Putnam's research reinforced and reinvigorated research that had been decades before. The fact that he used a similar location and culture as existing research meant that people reading his work for the first time could easily integrate it in with what they already knew.

### Observation

Just look around. You have a lifetime of experience in a world that includes both conservative and reformist actors. Have you seen any things that make good case studies?

This is the essence of field work. In some observational fields this is the core of how they do research. In some cases (like yours) it is just a part of the hypothesis creating process.